# New World family sharing suddenly stopped being accessible?

Tags: steam, technical-issues, steam-family-sharing, new-world

Recently I logged into my Steam account, only to find that New World that was 'family shared' with me stopped being available for play.

I know for a fact that no one is playing that game on the original account (my brother hasn't been playing).

Before the 'Purchase' option appeared, I had been playing the game on my account without any issues whatsoever. I've tried some of the suggested actions, such as re-authorizing the account, checking files integrity, resetting Winsock...

Does anyone have any idea on how to fix this/what might have caused this issue?

Update: Amazon has announced a fix!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Family sharing was recently disabled for New World.

From [Community Manager's post](https://forums.newworld.com/t/notice-family-sharing-update/509393) :

> Due to the increase of bots, gold sellers, and ban evaders, we decided to disable family sharing  November 4, 2021 10:00 AM (in your local timezone).
>
> This decision was not taken lightly and for players who utilize family sharing for a valid reason, we will update this post with instructions for assistance.

That post is now [updated](https://forums.newworld.com/t/notice-family-sharing-update/509393/2):

> We have compiled a list of players who used Family Sharing as intended and will grant ownership to those players. Watch for a notice from Steam once this has been completed.

So looks like if your account was not used for any suspicious stuff you could get access back!

Comment: God, no. I feared this, although I had not heard about it. Thank you so much!